# Where can I find a simple html app that allows site visitors to post comments to the page without registration?

Tags: html

I feel like this should be extremely simple to find on the web... but I haven't found it yet.

I'm looking for something really simple.

I want anyone who visits my page, who want to post a comment on A SINGLE PAGE, to be able to enter text into a text box and click "submit" and have the comment posted to the page.

no checking for spam, nothing complicated just simply adding the text to the page and calling it a day.

any ideas on where I can find such a thing?

Answer (score 2):

> Why don't you create one?

You can't do it with HTML only.

You need to store the value in database inorder to maintain those values on the next visit. So you have to write server side logic to update a table and then fetch those values on the next visit. If you store user specific data in tables then you can show each user what he earlier posted, and can hide other users data.